# CSVに含まれる異常値を任意の記号または空欄に置き換えたい

Tags: csv, emeditor

CSVファイルで以下の行列の観測値データ(nxmですが以下ではm=1)の例が存在するとします。

```
1
100
200
1000
```

50以下または500以上は異常値としてその異常値を、EmEditorでNAまたは空欄で置き換えられますか？

```
NA
100
200
NA
```

または

```
100
200
```

という出力が必要です。

0でおきかえないのは0にするとこのCSVファイルをほかのプログラムで読み込んで(Excelなど)平均値などの統計量を計算するときに、異常値も含めて計算されてしまうからです。

```
0
100
200
0
```

だと平均は75ですが

```
NA(または空欄)
100
200
NA(または空欄)
```

ですと平均は150です。

Answer (score 1):

以下の手順で可能です。

1. EmEditorで、CSVファイルをCSVセル選択モードで開いたら、該当の列のヘディングをクリックして列選択します。
2. Ctrl+Hを押して、[置換] ダイアログを表示します。
3. [選択した範囲のみ] チェック ボックスが設定されていることを確認して、[数値範囲] ラジオ ボタンをクリックします。
4. [数値範囲を入力] ダイアログが表示されるので、[最小値] に `500` と入力します (小数が存在しない場合は [整数のみ] も設定すると速くなります)。OK をクリックすると、検索する文字列が `[500 , ]` となります。このステップをスキップして、直接、検索する文字列に `[500 , ]` と入力しても構いません。
5. 検索する文字列が `[500 , ]` となっていることを確認し、置換後の文字列を `NA` として、[すべて置換] ボタンをクリックします。
6. 同様にして、検索する文字列を `[ , 50]`、置換後の文字列を `NA` としてすべて置換します。

[image: EmEditor 数値範囲を入力]

これを一度に行いたい場合には、次のようなマクロを作成して実行することもできます。このマクロを実行するには、まず、以下のマクロを `ReplaceNumbers.jsee` などのファイル名で保存します。そして、[マクロ] メニューから [選択] を選択して、保存したマクロを選択します。そして、CSVファイルをCSVセル選択モードで開いたら、**該当の列のヘディングをクリックして列選択してから**、 [マクロ] メニューの [実行] を選択してください。

```
batch_list = editor.filters;
batch_list.AddReplace("[500 , ]","NA",0,eeExFindNumberRange);
batch_list.AddReplace("[ , 50]","NA",0,eeExFindNumberRange);
document.selection.BatchReplace(batch_list,eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll,0);
```

なお、[カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [ステータス] ページで [平均値] を設定しておけば、ステータス バーに選択範囲の平均値が表示されます。

[image: カスタマイズ - ステータス - 選択範囲の数の平均]

Comment: 大変ありがとうございました。この方法ですと範囲の値を複数試すことで、異常値の置換も、異常値がどの行や列に存在するか、存在する異常値の値や異常値の個数もわかるので非常に便利です。